# How can I dynamically create a name for a mongo database with Python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm writing the backend of my app in Python and writing to a PyMongo database.

I'm setting up a few servers which I'd like to run simultaneously as nodes in a blockchain.  In my prototype, I need each node to create there own collection in my database for their version of the blockchain, so for example `blockchain-{insert node_id here}` for each.

I'm pretty new to python and have been self teaching myself but struggling to combine `.format` method with creating these collections.

I know that this works:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.my_blockchain
col_blockchain = db.name_of_blockchain
```

Result: Collection named "name_of_blockchain"

But when I try the following, I get an error:

```
col_blockchain = db['col_my_blockchain_{}'].format(node_id)
```

Result: Error:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'format' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Or when I try to save the name in a variable, I don't get a dynamic answer:

```
    col_blockchain_name = 'col_my_blockchain_{}'.format(node_id)
    col_blockchain = db.col_blockchain_name
```

Result: Collection named "col_blockchain_name" for each server running (so not dynamic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
col_blockchain = db['col_my_blockchain_{}'].format(node_id)
```

is looking for a dictionary element called `col_my_blockchain_{}` and when it has retrieved that it's trying to call the string `format` function on it. What you want to do is:

```
col_blockchain = db['col_my_blockchain_{}'.format(node_id)]
```

Which forms the dictionary key fully before trying to access it. All you need to   do is move the ]

Comment: That worked perfectly - thanks so much!  It now seems so obvious, I can't believe I didn't try that

Answer (score -1):

Use eval keyword, for calling mongo collection

```
eval('col_my_blockchain.{}'.format(node_id))
```

this works